# What is a group of type $(2,2)$?

Tags: p-adic-number-theory

This is a statement in Serre's *A Course in Arithmetic* (p. 18).

> If $p\ne2$, the group $\mathbb{Q}_p^*/\mathbb{Q}_p^{*2}$ is a group of
>   type $(2,2)$.

What is a group of type $(2,2)$?

Comment: For a prime $p$, a group of type $(p,p)$ is one that is a direct product of two groups of order $p$. So a group of type (2,2) is a product of two groups of order 2.

Comment: Yes, it is annoying when authors use undefined notation, in particular if it is not standard one: this time this seems to be closer to what Fuchs uses in his book: type $\,(2,2)\, $ means, apparently, *two* direct factors of order *two* each, or what we poor, miserable mortals would also call *the Klein group* $\,C_2\times C_2\, $ ,with $\,C_n=$ the cyclic group of order two.

Comment: Ah I see. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

I expose the cyclotomic structure of ${\bf Q}_p$ in [this previous answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/283293/what-is-the-index-of-the-p-th-power-of-mathbb-q-p-in-mathbb-q-p/301551#301551) (that is, I find the isomorphism class of ${\bf Q}_p^\times/({\bf Q}_p^\times)^n$ exactly for all primes $p$ and $n\ge1$). The simpler case ${\bf Q}_p^\times/({\bf Q}_p^\times)^2$ for odd $p$ is easier to deduce as being $C_2\times C_2$, the [Klein four group](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Klein_four-group). It would seem the "typing" system that Serre refers to has to do with either the $p$-primary or invariant factor decomposition of f.g. abelian groups (into cyclic groups whose orders are put into tuples), see [Wikipedia for more details](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finitely-generated_abelian_group#Classification).